# Changing Color of DataGridView Row when CheckBox is checked.

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a DataSet. I have a CheckBox Column. When I want the row to change color as soon as user checks a particular row. I am able to change the color with my code but for some reason unknown to me.. the color gets changed only when I leave the cell.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "ColCheck" Then
            If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColCheck").Value = True Then

                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
              ''' blah blah blah...
```

Comment: how about adding `DataGridView1.Refresh()`?

Comment: Still the same story.

Comment: Use the CellEndEdit ...

Comment: I'm not really familiar with VB, but wouldn't you have to write an event to handle the checkbox being clicked? 

I know I've had problems with "changed" events in C# in the past with textboxes, where they'd only update when I left the field.

Comment: When you use that method, it will fire when a change has occurred...

Comment: ah yes, `CellValueChanged` event itself occurs when you leave the edited cell, should try `CellEndEdit` as Mr CoDeXeR suggested

Comment: Yep, had that problem about 8 years ago; doesn't leave me lol

Comment: try using **Datagridview1__CellContentClick EVENT** .

Comment: I already have tried ` DataGridView1.EndEdit()` both before and after the line where I change color before posting the question.. No luck

Comment: CellContentClick not working for me

Comment: worked with cellclick command

Answer (score 0):

write this above your code

```
dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "ColCheck" Then
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColCheck").Value = True Then

    Dim isChecked As Boolean = DirectCast(dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).FormattedValue, [Boolean])
    If isChecked Then
              DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
    End If
End If
  End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure to add the ... Handles CellValueChanged to end of sub.. For some reason it didn't go for me.

Comment: This code Not working... 
However, I have found the solution.. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Than I am not sure just ran this and worked for me? Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have to use `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
        If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
            DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: As you can see I have not yet marked my answer as THE answer, if someone can give me another code that works .. I would be more than happy to accept that. Plus I will get +2 :D